# ZendFramework Headscript Helper - Make scripts unique

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

How can I ensure that the **headScript** and **headStyle helper include** css **files only once** when added?

The reason I am asking is that I would like to display some contents in a lightbox and all Flashmassages.E.g. notifications like profile successfully edited.

To display flashmessages in the lightbox i would like to check at the top of my layout script if they are set, in case they are i would like to attach the required javascript library using the headScript helper.

The problem is that I have **no control about the scripts which were already added** at this point. Maybe at a page where the library is needed for an other use case, it has already been added with addScript.

**How can I ensure all scripts are added only once to my helper?**

I already checked that these helpers extend **Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container_Standalone** which uses an ArrayObject internally to hold the data and provides getters & setter to the array object.

Maybe a solution here would be to check each time when adding a script file if it already exists using the [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classArrayObject.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the paths and filenames are the *same*, the files will only be added once. The Zend View Helpers should take care of that for you.

Comment: I tested this before asking the question and I experienced it differently but I am going to test it again now.

Comment: this solved it. maybe i just had typing errors in the first test I made before asking